# Cannot Login, error msg shows "To log in to this site, your browser must accept cookies from the domain"

Tags: 9, cookies

On my dev environment hosted on the cloud which has SSL, I added this to the settings.php

```
$secure = true; // if you only want to receive the cookie over HTTPS
$httponly = true; // prevent JavaScript access to session cookie
$samesite = 'none';

if(PHP_VERSION_ID < 70300) {
  session_set_cookie_params($maxlifetime, '/; samesite='.$samesite, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $secure, $httponly);
} else {
  session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => $maxlifetime,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    'secure' => $secure,
    'httponly' => $httponly,
    'samesite' => $samesite
  ]);
}
```

My goal was to set SESSION cookie to samesite = 'NONE'.

Login was working when I did this on Drupal 8, but now on Drupal Core 9.3.0,
when I login I get error message
"To log in to this site, your browser must accept cookies from the domain [domain_name]"

[image]

Comment: My first take would be to search this string. Then you know the place in core where it comes from, and when. Then you can compare the code at this place to Drupal 8 on https://git.drupalcode.org.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2946 It's the issue where that error message has been introduced.

Comment: Are cookies disabled in your browser by any chance?

Comment: @berliner  thanks, but haven't found out anything useful from the issue. Also cookies are enabled in my browser.

Comment: Yes, same issue in Drupal 9.4.5

Comment: Did you find any solution ? My Drupal version is 9.5.9, dev & live website which are running on server, there I am able to login, but I am facing this issue on my local setup, I can login in Firefox incognito mode, but apart from that in all browser I am facing this issue, even in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error message when Drupal *expects* there to be a session, communicated by the `check_logged_in`, but none can be found.

I've found myself in this situation myself when a miss-configured web server stripped the cookies from the request.

The leads to Drupal setting up the session, and adding the query parameters, but the cookie not being present in subsequent requests. Drupal then displays the

> your browser must accept cookies

message.

Likely the cookie settings you are adding cause the cookie to become invalidated somehow, so double check that the browser actually sends the cookies, and that they reach Drupal.